# Insert image file to MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, image, insert, jpeg

I'm working on a social-network type website for musicians that uses a MySql database on phpMyAdmin. I'm having a problem with the website inserting image files to the database, and then displaying them (for profile pictures). The images are stored as LONGBLOB in the database.

If I add a picture directly through phpMyAdmin, it works fine. It's a .jpg stored as a .bin in the LONGBLOB datatype according to the database. On my website I can query and display it perfectly using:

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<?php echo base64_encode($memberpicture);?>" 
ALT="Member does not have picture" WIDTH=100 HEIGHT=100></img>
```

However, if a website user creates a profile and inserts an image as a profile picture using the website's "create profile" functionality, it isn't displayed on their profile. Here is the select image code:

```
...
<div class="control-group">
    <div class="controls">
        <label>Band Picture</label>
        <input type="file" name="picture"/>
    </div>
</div>
...
```

And here is the insert code:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    foreach($_POST AS $key => $val) {
    $_SESSION[$key]=$val;
}

mysql_connect("***", "***", "***");
mysql_select_db("musicians");

//...declare other values(name, bio, etc...
$cpicture=$_POST['picture'];
$cpicture = stripslashes($cpicture);
$cpicture = mysql_real_escape_string($cpicture);

$profileInsert="INSERT INTO profile(PROFILE_BANDNAME,PROFILE_GENRE,PROFILE_BANDBIO,
    PROFILE_PICTURE,PROFILE_ART,PROFILE_MUSICVIDEO,PROFILE_PLAYLIST)
    VALUES ('$cbandname','$cgenre','$cbio','$cpicture','$cart','$cvideo','$cplaylist')"
or die(mysql_error());
```

If i look at the database, there is a file there after the insert, but it is extremely small (approx 16 bytes), and it cannot be viewed on either the website or directly from the database. It's a .bin stored as a .bin in the LONGBLOB datatype according to the database, as opposed to a .jpg stored as a .bin.
Any help with this insert would be much appreciated!

Comment: Why frodo why -- use filesystem please, or for performance Mongodb + GridFS

Comment: are you sure the picture is making it to the server? you could do something like copy($cpicture, "somepath") and just make sure it's there before you start trying to post it do database. maybe just show it directly after uploading it to make sure?

Answer (score 0):

Using filesystem would probably be better but if you insist on doing it your way how is this working as your code doesn't seem to be in a form, there is no method or submit button?

Comment: Yeah I realize it would probably be better to do the filesystem, but this project is due in 4 days for a class I'm in, and I feel like just making the LONGBLOB work. I only posted the relevant parts of the code, as my entire script per page is very long becuase there is a lot going on. The method for the first snippet is "post", and the second code snippet is from the page it posts to.

Comment: Do you have enctype="multipart/form-data" on your <form> element?

Comment: No, I just have <form action = "checkmusician.php" method = "post">, should I change it to <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action = "checkmusician.php" method = "post"> ?

Comment: Yes, you'll need that. See here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_enctype.asp

Comment: Just tried that addition to the form tag, still not working. Also, now there isn't even a .bin file that uploaded to the database, nothing was uploaded at all with that change (picture wise).

Answer (score 0):

I thing that the problem is in MySql Server Networking. Check the max_allowed_packet in your configuration :)

Comment: Max allowed file size is 2GB per file on my database, is that what you mean?

Comment: Max allowed packetlength to send/recieve from to server

Comment: I'm not sure how to find that figure, I'm using hostgator to host the domain and server if that helps...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this makes a difference, but your code for saving looks different from all of the first few results when i searched on google:

http://www.php-mysql-tutorial.com/wikis/mysql-tutorials/uploading-files-to-mysql-database.aspx
http://mirificampress.com/permalink/saving_a_file_into_mysql
http://bytes.com/topic/php/insights/740327-uploading-files-into-mysql-database-using-php

maybe just try a code swap.

I would echo the other comments/answers here regarding just using the file system. But if you are just trying to get it to work as you mentioned in some of your replies, just copy some working code from another site.