# How to send uploaded image path on directory(web directory) into mysql?.Is it possible to send simultaneously?

Tags: php, android

This is my php side,My IDE is Android Studio..So what can I do to make name and image to insert into mysql from here?

```
$name = $_POST["name"];
$image = $_POST["image"];

$decodedImage =base64_decode("$image");
file_put_contents("pictures/" . $name . ".JPG", $decodedImage);
```

Comment: images should never being inserted in a database.

Comment: do you have a solutions  @IgnazioC?

Comment: is not clear what you need. If you need to insert an image into a mysql database you can read this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15488239/insert-image-file-to-mysql-database although I strongly suggest to save the image on the filesystem and store only the id on the database.

Comment: so from here how can i send the id of the image on database? @IgnazioC

Answer (score 0):

Elaborating on [IgnazioC comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32072761/how-to-send-uploaded-image-path-on-directoryweb-directory-into-mysql-is-it-po/32073871#comment52042220_32072761), you can generate the image name, instead of using the one provided by the user.

```
$name = $_POST["name"];
$image = $_POST["image"];

$decodedImage =base64_decode("$image");
$imageId = md5(microtime(true));

file_put_contents("pictures/" . $imageId . ".JPG", $decodedImage);
```

After this you can save the `$imageId` variable in the database and stop using `$name = $_POST["name"];` as if it is not correctly handled it can be a security issue as I could provide the image name as `../whateverfile.jpeg` and access it from outside.

Another more elaborated thing would be to for example split the `$imageId` string into groups of 2 or 3 letters and create a directory structure with them, then save there the image. This would allow you to avoid the filesystem file limit per folder.

Comment: so the picture itself is on directory on web page,so can i send $imageId to mysql at the same time from this coding you provided? @Gori

Comment: @TamimiBrewster exactly, right after saving the image, you can insert the `$imageId` in MySQL :)

Comment: so do i need to put   $con=mysqli_connect... for this coding? @Gori

Comment: @TamimiBrewster yes, just like a normal insert to a database :)

If this answer solved your doubt mark it as the answer pls :)